# Is this series convergent if yes then why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The n-th term of series is as follows

$$u_n = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}$$

Does this series converge or diverge? **Since it was put on hold for "context".
I am an engineer. I couldn't find a good way to attack this problem and thought would try friendly people at math exchange. Except that this question was put on hold I found it humbling to find so many elegant ways people came up to attack this problem from simple run of the mill test to solve it by ab initio principles.

Comment: yes the series does converge

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is convergent.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\geqslant2$. Therefore, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}=\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^n\geqslant2^n$. So,$$\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^{n^2}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}\leqslant\frac1{2^n}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant from first principles.

Answer (score 1):

$|u_n|^{1/n}=(\frac{n}{{n+1}})^{n}=(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n$

Your turn !

Comment: Cauchy's test ?

Comment: No. better root test.

Comment: Root test. I think

Comment: Thanks! Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^x\geq1+x$, for $x\geq 0$

Then $u_n=\Big( 1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{-n^2}<(e^{\frac{1}{n}})^{-n^2}=e^{-n}$

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n<\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}=0\space\space\space\blacksquare$